# Stellaris 6/8/9000 part libraries for Eagle?

Tags: pcb, software, library, stellaris

Someone pointed me at the freeware version of Eagle as a good starter dev tool. So I start playing around and I can't seem to find a part library for the chips I want to use. I found a library (the works) on the eagle site but it doesn't have the right parts and I found a library on the TI/Luminary Mico site (that I think has the right part) but it wont load (it has .src files and I seem to need .lbr) despite the fact it has files tagged specifically as for eagle.

Does anyone know where I can get files that will work? (Or how to make the files I have work?)

Comment: Alternatively, learn to draw your own parts! (http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/tutorial_info.php?tutorials_id=110)

Comment: More often than not you have to make your own, especially for Eagle. Manufacturers sometimes provide symbols for professional-grade tools (OrCAD, Altium, PADS), but not Eagle. That's probably what those .src files are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ftp://ftp.cadsoft.de/eagle/userfiles/libraries/luminary-arm.lbr

Symbols and footprints for: 
LM3S101
LM3S102
LM3S301
LM3S310
LM3S315
LM3S316
LM3S328
LM3S601
LM3S610
LM3S613
LM3S615
LM3S628
LM3S6911
LM3S6918
LM3S6938
LM3S6950
LM3S6952
LM3S6965
LM3S801
LM3S811
LM3S812
LM3S815
LM3S828
LM3S8962

Comment: If the 4 things I could grep for, I think that's the only one I didn't...